# Fatal error: String index is out of bounds Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, stringindexoutofbounds

I'm trying to get the substring of text typed in UITextView. Here's my code:

```
let textString = state.textString
    let replacementTextRange = state.replacementRange
    let substringStart = textString.text.index(
          textString.text.startIndex,
          offsetBy: replacementTextRange.charIndex
        )

    let subStringEnd = textString.text.index(
      textString.text.startIndex,
      offsetBy: replacementTextRange.charIndex + replacementTextRange.length
    )

    let currentTextForReplacementRange = substringStart..<subStringEnd//crashing
let currentTextForReplacement = String(textString.text[currentTextForReplacementRange])
```

It's crashing when i try to add character at the end of textView.But works if i try to add text in the beginning or in the middle of textView. How do i fix this crash:Thread 1: Fatal error: String index is out of bounds

Comment: You’re beyond the range of your text. Try using the debugger to see the values of those indices and compare them to where in the string that position would be. It’s not always one to one since Unicode can be weird that way but for ascii it should match.

Comment: Where does `replacementTextRange` come from?  We may need to see more of your code.   The use of `charIndex` is suspicious for the reason that @user965972 mentioned... unicode characters don't have fixed widths and you *probably* shouldn't be adding lengths that way.

Comment: @ScottThompson, I”m guessing that it’s rather that the length of the replacement string is longer than the original string. So using the replacement string to compute a position in the original string is bound to be wrong and will quickly become apparent by just looking at some input and computed positions. You’re right that the provided code, without any examples, is insufficient to say for sure.